# GitLab CI Webhooks and Commit Hashes

Tags: git, webhooks, gitlab-ci

I am in the following situation: I have two GitLab repositories `master` and `slave` that both need to be combined in order to run a test.

At the moment I'm taking the following approach: Create a CI project for `master` that pulls `slave` as a build step and then runs the test.

Now I want to trigger the build whenever somebody pushes to `slave` as well. The appropriate way to do this seems to be via webhooks, so I added the following webhook to `slave`:

https://ci.foo.com/projects/1/build?token=19c72c17f0e69&ref=master

Now, when the build is triggered by `slave` I get the following build error:

```
cd /home/gitlab_ci_runner/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/project-1 && git reset --hard && git clean -fdx && git remote set-url origin https://gitlab-ci-token:19c72c17f0e69@git.foo.com/slave.git && git fetch origin
cd /home/gitlab_ci_runner/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/project-1 && git reset --hard && git checkout cc807f3023451165cd73a258b4e2b01edbc954a4
HEAD is now at b38bd72 fixed bar
fatal: reference is not a tree: cc807f3023451165cd73a258b4e2b01edbc954a4
```

The problem is that `cc807f3023451165cd73a258b4e2b01edbc954a4` is the last commit of `slave`, and not of `master`, so checking out fails.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this, or know a solution other than using webhooks for this situation?